# URL's Path are not working when deployed to IIS Server System

Tags: css, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have problem that when i deployed my ASP.NET MVC project to IIS Server System, the images url's add from CSS they are not taking exact path and in Angularjs unable send post or get request.

**CSS sample code**

```
<div class="container" style="background-image:url('../../Images/img/product-1.jpg')">
    <div class="text-left">Welcome</div>
</div>
```

**AngularJS sample code**

```
var app=angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);
app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
    $http({
         method:"POST",
         url:"/controller/action",
         data:{id:1}
    }.then(function(response){
           console.log(response)
      }, function(error){
          console.log(error)
     });
]});
```

so these are sample code what i have written in my project.
i have search internet i have found some solutions like

1. Installing StaticContent from add or remove features for IIS
2. changing application pool for authentication.
3. remove staticContent tags in web.config.

i have tried these thing evening i am unable solve my issue.

**my error are:**

> GET http://18.xxx.xxx.xxx/controller/action 404 (Not Found)
>
> GET http://18.xxx.xxx.xxx/Images/img/bg-img/top.jpg 404 (Not Found)

**actual url should load like this**

> GET http://18.xxx.xxx.xxx/myApplication/controller/action 404 (Not Found)
>
> GET http://18.xxx.xxx.xxx/myApplication/Images/img/bg-img/top.jpg 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the style mentioned in below style.
Notes: change the directly level.

```
<div class="container" style="background-image:url('~/Images/img/product-1.jpg')">
<div class="text-left">Welcome</div>
```

```
  <div class="container" style="background-image:url('@Url.Content("~/Images/img/product-1.jpg")')">
<div class="text-left">Welcome</div>
```

Explanation of ~ vs /:

/ - Site root

~/ - Root directory of the application

Comment: thanks for reply but its not working > https://18.xxx.xxx.xxx/home/~/Images/img/bg-img/gettyimages-474563751-2048x2048.jpg error message showing like this

Comment: Hi , Please let me know what is hierarchy of image location?

Comment: my location path is `C:/inetpub/wwwroot/myapplication/Images/img/bg-img/imge.jpg` so i have deployed to Default Web Site/myapplication

Comment: Remove the ~ , then check.

Comment: no its not working and i also like this `../../../images/img/imge.jpg` its not be select from root folder